# Optional node in linked list

Tags: swift, linked-list, option-type

I am practicing Swift Language.
I am solving Leetcode problems with playground in xcode.

I am confused by assining and binding optional value in linked list.

Here is my code.

```
     // Definition for singly-linked list.
      public class ListNode {
          public var val: Int
          public var next: ListNode?
          public init(_ val: Int) {
              self.val = val
              self.next = nil
          }
      }

    var l1 = ListNode(2)
    l1.next  = ListNode(4)
    //first error: here I have an error that editor explains "Value of optional type 'ListNode?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?"
    l1.next.next = ListNode(3)




    //second warning : editors explains that Comparing non-optional value of type 'ListNode' to nil always returns true
    while l1 != nil{
        print(l1.val)
        if let nextNode = l1.next{
            l1 = nextNode
        }
    }
```

for the first error, if I put ! for the unwrapping, it still shows error.

> l1.next!.next! = ListNode(3) or l1.next.next! = ListNode(3)

I thought I could unwrapping because I am sure that I put right node for the second node.

I tried this also

```
    var l1 = ListNode(2)
    l1.next?  = ListNode(4)
    l1.next!.next? = ListNode(3)
```

then I would get

> Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
>   (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

please let me understand right use of optional expression.

Comment: you need to assign value  for "next" in init function

Comment: I thought that next will be init with nil value. isn't it?

Comment: @UdayBabariya It is not reason for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID245),

> Optional chaining is a process for querying and calling properties,
>   methods, and subscripts on an optional that might currently be nil. If
>   the optional contains a value, the property, method, or subscript call
>   succeeds; if the optional is nil, the property, method, or subscript
>   call returns nil. Multiple queries can be chained together, and the
>   entire chain fails gracefully if any link in the chain is nil.

You can update your code as follows

```
// Definition for singly-linked list.
public class ListNode {
    public var val: Int
    public var next: ListNode?
    public init(_ val: Int) {
        self.val = val
        self.next = nil
    }
}

var l1 = ListNode(2)
l1.next  = ListNode(4)
l1.next?.next = ListNode(3) 
//By using the '?' operator, you're essentially saying that if l1's next is nil,
//do nothing; otherwise, assign ListNode(3) to it
```

For your second issue, the warning here is coming up because you are checking l1(non-optional) against nil and this will always return true in your case. You want some sort of recursion. Try the following

```
func printValuesFrom(_ node: ListNode) {
    print(node.val)
    if let next = node.next {
        printValuesFromNode(next)
    }
}

printValuesFrom(l1)
```

Comment: For the second issue, log shows only 2 and 4. I want to know right expression to optional binding.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error here

```
//first error: here I have an error that editor explains "Value of optional type 'ListNode?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?"
l1.next.next = ListNode(3)
```

Because  `l1.next` is `Optional` type of `ListNode`, so it is possible that it could be nil. so it is not allowing you  to assign  `.next` two time without unwrap it.

```
l1.next?.next = ListNode(3)
```

For second case

```
while l1 != nil{
        print(l1.val)
        if let nextNode = l1.next{
            l1 = nextNode
        }
    }
```

**EDIT2**

```
var node  = l1.next 

while node != nil {
   print (node.value)
  node = node.next
}
```

Here `l1` is not optional. `l1.next` is optional so you should

use   `while l1.next != nil` to loop next element. otherwise there is no need for loop here

**EDIT**

Why `l1.next!.next! = ListNode(3)` create crash ?

First of all don't forcefully unwrap any of optional value.

Here what you are doing is for first `next` it is fine. you can get next object but for second `next` in which you are assigning new value 
`ListNode(3)` is still nil so your app is throwing error .

Hope it is helpful to you

Comment: For the second issue, log shows only 2 and 4. I want to know right expression to optional binding. –

Comment: @JanghyupLee You should keep Head node also. in some global `var`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way...

```
 public class ListNode {
        public var val: Int
        public var next: ListNode?
        public init(_ val: Int, _ next: ListNode?) {
            self.val = val
            self.next = next
        }
    }

    var l1 = ListNode(1,nil)

    var l2 = ListNode(2,nil)
    l1.next  = l2 

  // or l1.next = ListNode(2,nil)
```